# spring profiles in .yaml. How do you set up configuration properties?

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, yaml, spring-profiles

I am a spring newbie and a .yaml newbie as well and I´m starting to get cross eyed googling answers(a lot of them are very outdated or just confusing).

Currently I have a application.yaml that looks like this

```
spring:
  profiles.active: TEST
---
spring:
  profiles: DEV
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.web: INFO
    se.some.url: DEBUG
api:
  url:
     one: test.url
    two : test.url
certification:
  policies:
      one : 0.0.0.0.0
      two : 0.0.30.0

---
spring:
  profiles: TEST
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.web: INFO
    se.some.url: DEBUG
api:
  url:
     one: test.url
    two : test.url
certification:
  policies:
      one : 0.0.0.0.0
      two : 0.0.30.0
```

I need to be able to use the values of the certification.policies and api.url in my code and make sure everything loads depending on with profile is active.

I do get that a config class needs to be created.

But what annotation should be used? 
How do I set the profile?
How do I get the value?

Grateful for any help!

Comment: You have written correctly

Comment: You can specify at launch -Dspring.profiles.active=dev or env variable export spring_profiles_active=dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read [this documentation about externalized configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties).

With `@ConfigurationProperties("some-property")` you tell Spring to initialize the fields with the values configured in your `.yml` file.

The active profile can be specified when starting your jar. You can e.g. specify the active profile via command line: `--spring.profiles.active=dev,hsqldb`. [See the documentation for more information.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html#boot-features-profiles)